# Visual Studio Installer company name on Windows 10

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installation, windows-installer

I'm using Visual Studio Installer to make a setup proyect for my solution. This is my setup properties example:

[image: Setup properties]

Once I install my result, if I go to Control Panel and try to find my software, I see this, including software name and company name:

[image: Control panel > Installed software]

The problem comes with the new Windows 10 configuration, where I cannot see company name for some reason:

[image: Windows 10 Configuration > Installed software]

Any idea to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The displayed value on Windows 10 is the 'Publisher' property. You can't set this in the installer project but instead is read from the code-signing certificate, used to sign the MSI, of your company (if they own one)

[Answer from Microsoft Community](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/b2338666-ae63-47db-86cb-5f7c12736d11/how-to-specify-publisher-of-an-msi-file?forum=iewebdevelopment)

You need to digitally sign your MSI.  One set of instructions can be found [here](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140234(office.10).aspx); MSDN contains [more information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/ee290833(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Comment: First line in instructions link says: "This content is no longer actively maintained. It is provided as is, for anyone who may still be using these technologies, with no warranties or claims of accuracy with regard to the most recent product version or service release.". Is this obsolete? Second link doesnt work. I'll take a look at the answer from MS Community.

Comment: Did not check the date on that source, its old, but signing your .exe, .dll and .msi files hasn't changed as far as I know. [dont forget the timestamping](https://blog.codeinside.eu/2017/11/30/signing-with-signtool-dont-forget-the-timestamp/)